# React Fullcalendar v5 with custom text fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have a question about adding events in fullcalendar-react.

Normally, we would add events by clicking on the calendar, but I would like to prepare a separate text field of my own and add events from there.

↓Here's the UI what I'm thinking
[image]

Is there any way to make this happen using fullcalender?

Sorry for my bad English.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, just call the [addEvent](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent) function when the Submit button is pressed. You have to call addEvent anyway even when selecting on the calendar. The process is essentially the same, except the event data comes from your form instead of from the calendar selection info.

Comment: Okay, How do I call the react [eventAdd handler](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react)
?
`<FullCalendar eventAdd={} />`

Comment: It's not a handler it's a function. Go to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react and read the section called "Calendar API" which explains how to call functions in fullcalendar react.

Comment: I'm the question you said `Normally, we would add events by clicking on the calendar`, which implies you have done adding events before. If you have, you must have used addEvent for that.

Comment: Yes. I was able to add it by clicking on it.
I don't know how to add an event to trigger a button click instead. I am having trouble finding an example of using react...

Comment: Clicking on the calendar does not, by itself, add an event. There must have been some code behind that to handle the selection and create an event object from the data, and then add it to the calendar. And the link I've just provided shows how to get the calendar API object when using react, and how to call a calendar function.

Comment: After filling out the form and clicking the submit button, I’d like to handle the selection and create an event object based on the target date I filled out.
I can add an event to the calendar by triggering a click on the calendar, but I think that triggering just a button will result in a null object.

Comment: You don't need to handle the selection after clicking - handling the selection is a UI event in fullcalendar. You're replacing that UI interaction with the UI interaction of filling in the form and clicking the button. When the button is clicked, you must run some JavaScript which will take the values from the input fields, create an event object, and pass into the addEvent function (just like you must be doing when you click on the calendar)

Comment: I don't know React specifically, but here are some vanilla JS fullCalendar demos to illustrate what I'm saying: 1) just clicking on the calendar will make a selection (when "selectable" is enabled) but it _doesn't_ create an event (contrary to what you still seem to be claiming): https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/PoJaLKJ 2) Clicking on the calendar to create an event just requires that you add some extra code in the "select" handler, and invoke addEvent(): https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/WNZymEy ...

Comment: ... 3) Handling the submit event on a form (instead of making a selection), and adding an event that way: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/Yzrvgrp . So all you have to do is find the React equivalent of handling the "submit" event of a form, and you're 90% of the way there.

Comment: It's so easy to understand.
Thank you for providing so many examples
You are my hero.

Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I wasn't really sure exactly where you were stuck, hence the different examples.